# Where to place logic to take user to appropriate home page when accessing application with persisted login in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with multiple Areas that have multiple home screens, but a single login page. In my Login action on successful Login I check the User's type and take them to the appropriate Area/Controller/Action.

However, what if a user logs in, closes there web browser and comes back to the application. Their login is still persisted. Where can I still do the User Type check and take them to the appropriate home screen?

Just to make it clear I am using ASP.NET Core Identity w/ Individual User accounts and added a UserType property to the ApplicationUser class. So in my Login action I am able to call _userManager.FindByEmail(email) and then check the UserType property. Have no idea how to replicate this on application start.

Comment: what type of authentication do you use?

Comment: @DaniDev The default ASP.NET Core Identity that comes with ASP.NET CORE MVC Individual User accounts template.

Comment: is User Type associated with that identity?

Comment: @DaniDev correct. Added it to the ApplicationUser class. So in my Login action I am able to call _userManager.FindByEmail and then check the UserType property. Have no idea how to replicate this on application start.

Comment: I have to admit I have not worked with core, But in asp.net 4.5 there are several places where you can perform this check prior to individual/requests view loads (not necessarily in login).

Comment: maybe a custom response attribute

Comment: @DaniDev I believe it is in Startup.cs, but just don't know how to access the logged in User's type and redirect from there.

Comment: The easiest approach is probably a filter (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters). However, you can probably accomplish it with a generic middleware component as well.